# how to link another file on one page html?

Tags: html

I am early for frontend developer.

I'm making one page html, all goes well, I meaning scroll to div running smoothly.

But if i add

```
<li><a href="#language">Language</a></li>
<li><a href="login.html">Log in</a></li>
```

can not link to the file without "#".

Note : file is in a one folder with index.html

How to link another file on one page html without "#"?
any suggestion for me?
thanks in advance :)

Comment: That's the right syntax. What error are you getting?

Comment: thanks for reply.. nothing error on firebug, is there a jquery code if no "#" can link to the page login.html??

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: do you know code jquery, if without "#", can link to file login.html?

Comment: I know jquery, but what you're asking for is how links work normally.  I don't have enough information to understand what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

you can add file name before div id.

```
<li><a href="anotherfile.html#test">Another page</a></li>
```